# Profile plot trouble in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, dem, profile

I'm new to GRASS and GIS environments in general, and I recently faced a problem when trying to get the profile plot from a DTM. When I draw the transect, instead of the plot, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS
6.4.2\etc\wxpython\gui_modules\profile.py", line 468, in
OnCreateProfile

self.DrawPlot()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS
6.4.2\etc\wxpython\gui_modules\profile.py", line 490, in
DrawPlot

marker=self.properties['marker']['type'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS 6.4.2\Python27\lib
\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\plot.py", line 342,
in __init__

PolyPoints.__init__(self, points, attr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS 6.4.2\Python27\lib
\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\plot.py", line 145,
in __init__

self._points =
_Numeric.array(points).astype(_Numeric.Float64)
ValueError
:
could not convert string to float: *
```

Does anyone out there have an idea about my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please update to the latest GRASS GIS 6 version which should address this problem:

http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/6.4.3-News